# Find the Second Zero

Tags: code-golf, number

## Challenge

Given an integer in 32-bit [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) format, return the index of the *second* least-significant zero digit in the binary representation, where an index of `0` represents the least significant bit, and an index of `31` represents the most significant bit.

If there is no second zero, you may return 0, any negative number, any falsy value, or report an error in a way that makes sense in your language.

You may use 1-indexing if you prefer, but the test cases below will use 0-indexing.

You may use unsigned integers if you prefer; if you do, then you must handle integers in the range `[0, 2^32)`. If you use signed integers, you must handle integers in the range `[-2^31, 2^31)`. The test cases here will use signed integers, but note that `-x` (signed) is `2^32 - x` (unsigned).

## Test Cases

```
0  (0b00)        -> 1
1  (0b001)       -> 2
10 (0b1010)      -> 2
11 (0b01011)     -> 4
12 (0b1100)      -> 1
23 (0b010111)    -> 5
-1 (0b11..11)    -> None
-2 (0b11..10)    -> None
-4 (0b11..00)    -> 1
-5 (0b11..1011)  -> None
-9 (0b11..10111) -> None
2^31-2 (0b0111..1110) -> 31
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins!

Comment: Can we use an unsigned integer instead?

Comment: Yes you may, as long as you then handle integers in the range `[0, 2^32)`.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13288/69054) for those who can see deleted posts

Comment: Are we taking the integer or the string `0b...` as input?

Comment: You should take the integer as input. You may take the decimal representation as a string if you wish, but not the binary representation

Comment: If we take unsigned is there *always* a second zero, since they are not 32-bit, or are we to assume a 32-place limit?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I guess not, since I was corrected on my Jelly answer with `2^32-1` because I wasn't supposed to return `33`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Erik's answer is correct. I've updated the challenge spec to reflect that you should handle 32-bit integers whether you choose to take them as signed or unsigned

Comment: What should be the behavior of the code for 2^32-1=2147483647 as input?

Comment: @mdahmoune If you are taking signed integers, that number is outside the input range. If you are taking unsigned numbers, then that number is `0b1111...1111` (the signed equivalent being `-1`). Having no second zero, you should report an error. This is one of the given test cases.

Comment: May we return *any* of those results if the input has no second zero bit, or does it need to be a well-defined result?

Comment: You should stay consistent. I'll say you can return any non-positive integer as one of the options though

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 45 bytes

```python
lambda n:[i for i in range(32)if n|1<<i>n][1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjpTIS2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw9hIMzNNIa/G0MYm0y4vNtow9j@aCiNTTSsuzoKizLwShUwdhTSNTM3/AA)

Uses 0-indexing, unsigned numbers, and throws an error on no second zero.

Simply creates a list of indices of non-set bits, from lowest to highest, and returns the second entry.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first post!

Comment: Thanks! I'm still really new to golfing trickery in Python, so I'm glad this code didn't get golfed down immediately.

Comment: Great :) what about n=2147483647?

Comment: @mdahmoune 2**31-1 should error out since its binary representation in 32 bits is 0b01111111111111111111111111111111, which doesn't have a second 0.  Unless I'm missing something...

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (ES6), 34 bytes

Returns a 0-based index, or `-1` if no second zero is found.

```js
n=>31-Math.clz32((n=~n^~n&-~n)&-n)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

n=>31-Math.clz32((n=~n^~n&-~n)&-n)

console.log(f(0))       // -> 1
console.log(f(1))       // -> 2
console.log(f(10))      // -> 2
console.log(f(11))      // -> 4
console.log(f(12))      // -> 1
console.log(f(23))      // -> 5
console.log(f(-1))      // -> None
console.log(f(-2))      // -> None
console.log(f(-4))      // -> 1
console.log(f(-5))      // -> None
console.log(f(-9))      // -> None
console.log(f(2**31-2)) // -> 31
```

#### Alternate expression

```js
n=>31-Math.clz32((n=~n^++n&-n)&-n)
```

---

### Recursive version, 42 bytes

Returns a 0-based index, or `false` if no second zero is found.

```js
f=(n,p=k=0)=>n&1||!k++?p<32&&f(n>>1,p+1):p
```

#### How?

```js
f=(n,p=k=0)=>                               // given n, p, k
             n&1||                          // if the least significant bit of n is set
                  !k++?                     // or this is the 1st zero (k was not set):
                       p<31&&               //   return false if p is >= 31
                             f(n>>1,p+1)    //   or do a recursive call with n>>1 / p+1
                                        :p  // else: return p
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(n,p=k=0)=>n&1||!k++?p<32&&f(n>>1,p+1):p

console.log(f(0))       // -> 1
console.log(f(1))       // -> 2
console.log(f(10))      // -> 2
console.log(f(11))      // -> 4
console.log(f(12))      // -> 1
console.log(f(23))      // -> 5
console.log(f(-1))      // -> None
console.log(f(-2))      // -> None
console.log(f(-4))      // -> 1
console.log(f(-5))      // -> None
console.log(f(-9))      // -> None
console.log(f(2**31-2)) // -> 31
```

#### Alternate version suggested by Neil, 41 bytes

Returns a 0-based index, or throws a *too much recursion* error if no second zero is found.

```js
f=(n,c=1)=>n%2?1+f(~-n/2,c):c&&1+f(n/2,0)
```

Comment: 41-byte recursive version: `f=(n,c=1)=>n%2?1+f(~-n/2,c):c&&1+f(n/2,0)`

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
|‘‘&~l2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/mUcMMIFKryzH6//@/kTEA)

It outputs something not in the range [1,31] if there isn't the second zero. This includes `32` `33` and `(-inf+nanj)`. I guess that makes some sense.

It calculates `log(((x|(x+1))+1)&~x)/log(2)`.

Comment: `-inf+nanj` I didn't think that could even exist

Comment: It does not output `(-inf+nanj)` for an input of `2147483647` which has a binary representation of 31 1s, hence no second zero in 32-bit signed notation (this is why it's so much shorter than mine and Erik's answers).

Comment: Actually, when *does* it produce `(-inf+nanj)`?

Comment: ...ah I think worked it out, you're using the signed option?

Answer (score 4):

## IA-32 machine code, <s>14</s> 13 bytes

Hexdump:

```
F7 D1 0F BC C1 0F B3 C1 0F BC C9 91 C3
```

Disassembly listing:

```
0:  f7 d1                   not    ecx
2:  0f bc c1                bsf    eax,ecx
5:  0f b3 c1                btr    ecx,eax
8:  0f bc c1                bsf    ecx,ecx
b:  91                      xchg   eax, ecx
c:  c3                      ret
```

Receives input in `ecx`; output is in `al`. Returns 0 on error.

First of all, it inverts the input, so it can use the bit scan instructions to look for set bits. It looks for the least significant set bit, resets it, looks for least significant set bit again, and returns the result.

If the bit-scan instruction doesn't find any set bit, the Intel documentation says the output is undefined. However, in practice all processors leave the destination register unchanged in this case (as noted by Cody Gray, AMD documentation describes this behavior as mandatory).

So, there are the following cases:

1. No zero bits (binary 111...1): ecx is set to 0 by `not` and remains 0
2. One zero bit: ecx is set to 0 by `btr` and remains 0 after `bsf`
3. Two zero bits: ecx is set to the proper value by `bsf`

Comment: It is only Intel's documentation that says bit scans on 0 are undefined. AMD's documentation explicitly documents that the destination is unchanged. If you want to avoid this behavior, you would normally add the REP prefix to get either LZCNT or TZCNT, but that increases the byte count, which is naturally undesirable for code golf.

Comment: You're actually doing too much work here. The challenge doesn't require you to discriminate between the case where there are no zero bits and the case where there's only 1 zero bit. It allows you to return 0 (or any negative value) in both cases. So, although the 1-byte `SALC`+`DEC` is *extremely* clever, you can shave off a byte by just using whatever is in `ECX` as of the second `BSF` instruction. The only thing that requires is a 1-byte `XCHG` to get the result in `EAX` so it can be returned. In other words, `not ecx; bsf eax, ecx; btr ecx, eax; bsf ecx, ecx; xchg eax, ecx; ret`

Comment: [Here's a "try it online" link for the above](https://tio.run/##TVDLTsMwELz7K1ZBleLWQXkApUrhQFB/glSRcZzWUuog20UWVX@dsHFbCR/2ObuzY5HshBhHMWjrQOy5Af/8VA2t/NjCC0S13yxr/57VPt3U/q2qfXWLi3/xVF/VfoV5VUQlsY47JUBpB03DnTPq8@hk08Rxx60TvO8phXiOVBuvaYw4imxX5pIQcqe06I@thLV1rRru96@ETNsOXOkJDtzsBAsHz@dT8k3hRAgESs1MeYudtM4GLSdIWcYyNGhzlhcsyViSs@SBJY8sWbHUL7vwJJzDfDcYCGQKx9MS3RqyHP1iQbEd@AA0Ni8saluGirloQWmxpuUF9WVwURdHVuJXt82PNEM8ayfVs7bWEcOb6TR9nuBGuqPRSEnO4/grup7v7JgcivwP "C (gcc) – Try It Online"). Since you're using `ECX` as the input register, we need to tell GCC to use the fastcall calling convention.

Answer (score 4):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>44</s> 38 bytes

```java
i->i.numberOfTrailingZeros(~i&-i-2)&31
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY4xT8MwEIXn5ld4qhLJtkgKAwEiMYDEgDqkE4jhmjjhgmNbtlOpQu1fDweNxBtO7066974BDiCsU2Zov2Y37TU2rNEQAnsFNOw7YaQQIdK9QwOaDfQhp4hadpNpIlojd/bFxOdluyeveuUrZtjDjKJCaaZxr/y223lAjaZ/U96G9IxrgaLI1pt8vvvrWfqXuoPFlo1EkdbR09f7BwPfh2yB@tU/S4hewSipu74426VXPOc5DZoFLzZc5FwUXFxzccPFLT8XVVXlWbJayRFcasoSnNPHx0Ahmeysf4Lmc@tb5VWb1scQFaVOsSwd0URtsgv0KTnNPw)

Returns 0 if no second zero bit exists.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, ...  <s>194 191</s>     186 Bytes

```
static int f(int n){char[] c=Integer.toBinaryString(n).toCharArray();int j=0,o=2^32-2,i=c.length,l=i-1;if(n<0|n>o)return 0;for(;j<2&i>0;j+=c[--i]==48?1:0);if(j==2)return l-i;return 0;}
```

*-159 Bytes for using smaller variable names and removing whitespace*
*-25 Bytes, after taking even shorter variables and thanks to @KevinCruijssen tips*
*-18 Bytes, more whitespaces, function name*
*-3 Bytes, thanks to @KevinCruijssen, shortening if condition*
*-5 Bytes, Thanks to @Arnold Palmer, @KevinCruijssen, shortening loop*

### Ungolfed

```
public static int getPosSecondZero2(int number){
    int overflow = 2^32-2;
    if(number < 0 || number > overflow){
        return 0;
    }    
    String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(number);   
    char[] binaryCharArray = binaryString.toCharArray();    
    int count = 0;
    int idx = binaryCharArray.length;
    int length = binaryCharArray.length -1;
    while(count < 2 && idx>0){
        idx--;
        if(binaryCharArray[idx] == '0'){
            count++;
        }   
    }
    if(count == 2)
        return length-idx;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! There are quite a few things you can golf: `static ` can be removed; `if(n<0||n>o){return 0;}`can be `if(n<0|n>o)return 0;` (`|` instead of `||` and no brackets); `bs`, `bsa`, etc. can all be single characters (never use multi-byte variable/method names in code-golf); You can combine `int`s, like this: `int o=2^32-2,c=0,i=x.length,l=i-1;`. And there are some more things to golf. [Tips for golfing in Java](https://tinyurl.com/yb2z65sp) and [Tips for golfing in all languages](https://tinyurl.com/y8kzo4vm) might be interesting to read. Again welcome, and enjoy your stay! :)

Comment: I think there are still a couple spaces you can remove in your variable declarations. Welcome! :)

Comment: @musicman523 Thanks, yeah fixed it. 194 for now :)

Comment: `if(c[i]=='0'){j++;}` can still be golfed to `if(c[i]==48)j++;` for -3 bytes :) EDIT: Or better yet: `while(j<2&&i>0){i--;if(c[i]=='0'){j++;}}` can be `for(;j<2&i>0;j+=c[i--]==48?1:0);` for -8 bytes.

Comment: Your 8 Byte suggestion will throw an ArrayOutOfBoundException, or I'm just too dense to implement it correctly :)

Comment: @0x45 I believe if you change @KevinCruijssen's code to `for(;j<2&i>0;j+=c[--i]==48?1:0);` it should work.  The error is coming from `i` being the length of the string, so initially you're trying to index past the bounds of the array.  If you do a pre-decrement (as shown in the updated snippet), then the first time you use it it will access `c[c.length-1]` like in your original code.

Comment: @ArnoldPalmer Ah, you're indeed right. I placed the `--` incorrectly.. My bad, sorry _0x45_.

Comment: Currently should fail most test cases:
The complete int range has to be supported -> the <0 and overflow? check has to be removed. `2^32-2` is the same as `2^30` which is `28` (`^` is xor, not pow).
Integer#toBinaryString does not pad the string with leading zeros -> will fail iff the result would be any of the leading zeros.

Besides that the code can be further golfed: The whitespace in `char[] c` is not required.
One return statement with a ternary operator is shorter.
`j+=c[--i]==48?1:0` can be replaced with `j+=1-c[--i]/49`. `l=i-1 ... l-i` could be replaced with `l=i ... l+~i`.

Comment: [Example in Java8](https://tio.run/##RZDBboMwDIbP7VNESJsSLWEQukOhMHXTJu0w7dDdqh4yCG0YBJSESqjqXp25K9J8sBzL/v1/qcRRsLaTuiq@x67/qlWO8lpYi96F0ug0RxDWCQf9UmlRowo2/N6p2i97nTvVav@zfdPudXqtoJZ7aTKkUTpqlp3ygzDbXZ56nl@2phEOezcRtx7VvmufQNQMG2eU3mNNCLSeYX5tjBgwSZR2qEoDqtKIJ7CNk2rFb1UWJNVdGrJ8y5ja3S@WJDHS9UbDcMofo5CpOEjOY/Lnf@KaMI6tKlADdPh6dbtDwuwtmWAv8c9onZGi8YFpc63aEgc0pCEkyJzyiLKQMk7ZgrIHypb0h2dZFpL5bOY3osM6jkXX1cPaggi5/MCLyA8fppBGFngzWCdBtXdx3IEbV2tyNX2en8df)

Comment: Actually, `j+=1-c[--i]/49` should be `j+=~c[--i]&1`.

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL, 20 bytes

```
{2⊃(⍳32)/⍨~⌽⍵⊤⍨32⍴2}
```

Uses 1-indexing, throws `INDEX ERROR` in case of no second zero.

**How?**

`⍵⊤⍨` - encode `⍵` as a

`32⍴2` - binary string of length 32

`⌽` - reverse

`~` - negate (0→1, 1→0)

`(⍳32)/⍨` - compress with the range 1-32 (leaving indexes of zeros)

`2⊃` - pick the second element

Comment: You could save a lot of bytes using Where (`⍸`)

Comment: @TwiNight I use dyalog 14

Comment: TIO has Dyalog 16 if you need

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
B¬Ṛ;1,1ḣ32TḊḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//QsKs4bmaOzEsMeG4ozMyVOG4iuG4ov///zEx)

Uses 1-indexing, gets unsigned integer as input. Returns `0` for not found.

Comment: This outputs `33` for the input `4294967295` (`2^32-1`, the 32-bit unsigned equivalent of `-1`)

Comment: @musicman523 Hmm, something smells fishy...

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
,4BUFḣ32¬TḊḢ
```

A monadic link, taking an integer, using the unsigned option and returning the 1-indexed result (returns 0 when none exists).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//LDRCVUbhuKMzMsKsVOG4iuG4ov///zEx)**

or

```
32Ḷ2*|€n⁸TḊḢ
```

**[Try that](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//MzLhuLYyKnzigqxu4oG4VOG4iuG4ov///zEx)**

#### How?

1.

```
,4BUFḣ32¬TḊḢ - Link: number, n   e.g. 14
,4           - pair with 4            [14,4]
  B          - to binary              [[1,1,1,0],[1,0,0]]
   U         - upend                  [[0,1,1,1],[0,0,1]]
    F        - flatten                [0,1,1,1,0,0,1]
     ḣ32     - head to 32             [0,1,1,1,0,0,1] (truncates the right if need be)
        ¬    - not (vectorises)       [1,0,0,0,1,1,0]
         T   - truthy indexes         [1,5,6]
          Ḋ  - dequeue                [5,6]
           Ḣ - head                   5
             -   if the dequeued list is empty the head yields 0
```

2.

```
32Ḷ2*|€n⁸TḊḢ - Link: number, n   e.g. 14
32Ḷ          - lowered range of 32    [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...,31]
   2*        - 2 exponentiated        [ 1, 2, 4, 8,16,32, ...,2147483648]
     |€      - bitwise or for €ach    [15,14,14,14,30,46, ...,2147483662]
        ⁸    - chain's right argument 14
       n     - not equal?             [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, ..., 1]
         T   - truthy indexes         [ 1, 5, 6, ..., 32]
          Ḋ  - dequeue                [ 5, 6, ..., 32]
           Ḣ - head                   5
             -   if the dequeued list is empty the head yields 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86_64 machine code, <s>34</s> 32 bytes

Not sure if this is the right approach, quite a lot of bytes (turns out it is [not](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132979/48198)):

```
31 c0 83 c9 ff 89 fa 83 e2 01 83 f2 01 01 d1 7f 09 ff c0 d1 ef eb ee 83 c8 ff 83 f8 1f 7f f8 c3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVFhb4IwEP3Or7iwmLR6LBQ007HtjwyzYFu0iSum1IXN@NvZFSrh@l7veK8PkNlRynF8Mlaer0rDW@@V6Z5PH0kiO9t7kKfGweHXa9kp/bmHd0jroRT1IPN62JaEu3poW@IBm7mni3rIxczbyEMpqhd6No@a4BF6mrg@UOnouY2eQU9ctLMucFmmVZIY6@G7MZYF0rijxCnpchk2PxxuSQIQZhZd9eBe976f3gHgBjkKFLTQWmBRYiYwKzBbY7bBbIc5nThdGu5VNHC6v56jxQ0Ekg7XZLOZxGQUsQx3kJGu7RxMKQ2J8orgDURBuFrFmACWRnM4s6@mjqMOCzK25Izzxw/gzPJq1lwcTVuW9jSw6utPu44tFCfdQtWe6eGipdfqlba8tinSh8BHfrPn4Zh7cHLaX52lZMl9HP8B)

```
second_zero:
  # Set eax = 0
  xor  %eax, %eax
  # Set ecx = -1
  xor %ecx,%ecx
  not %ecx

  # Loop over all bits
Loop:
  # Get current bit
  mov %edi, %edx
  and $0x1, %edx
  # Check if it's zero and possibly increment ecx
  xor $0x1, %edx
  add %edx, %ecx
  # If ecx > 0: we found the position & return
  jg Return
  # Increment the position
  inc %eax
  # Shift the input and loop
  shr %edi
  jmp Loop

Fix:
  # If there's not two 0, set value to -1
  xor %eax,%eax
  not %eax

Return:
  # Nasty fix: if position > 31 (e.g for -1 == 0b11..11)
  cmp $31, %eax
  jg  Fix

  ret
```

Thanks @CodyGray for `-2` bytes.

Comment: Looping through all of the bits is probably not the right approach, either for code golfing or for real world. The real breakthrough will be using one of the instructions that allow you to manipulate all 32 (or 64) bits at once, like `BSF`, `BSR`, `POPCNT`, `BT`, etc. Anatolyg has [submitted a solution along these lines](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132979/58518). I haven't yet determined if it can be beat. :-p

Comment: By the way, a potentially useful code-golfing trick to set a register to -1 is to OR it with -1. For example, `or ecx, -1`. That's 3 bytes, 1 byte shorter than XOR+NEG. This isn't a good trick when *not* golfing because it introduces a false read dependency on the destination register, but there you'd just use `mov ecx, -1` and spend the 5 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), 149 bytes

```
2 base swap >s nip decimal s:len 32 swap n:- ( "0" s:<+ ) swap times s:rev null s:/ a:new swap ( "0" s:= if a:push else drop then ) a:each swap 1 a:@
```

**Commented code**

```
: f \ n -- a1 a2 n 

  \ decimal to binary conversion
  2 base swap >s nip decimal     

  \ 32bit formatting (padding with 0)            
  s:len 32 swap n:- ( "0" s:<+ ) swap times  

  \ put reversed binary number into an array 
  s:rev null s:/

  \ build a new array with position of each zero 
  a:new swap ( "0" s:= if a:push else drop then ) a:each

  \ put on TOS the position of the 2nd least least-significant zero digit
  swap 1 a:@
;
```

**Usage and output**

```
ok> : f 2 base swap >s nip decimal s:len 32 swap n:- ( "0" s:<+ ) swap times s:rev null s:/ a:new swap ( "0" s:= if a:push else drop then ) a:each swap 1 a:@ ;

ok> [0, 1, 10, 11, 12, 23, -1, -2, -4, -5, -9, 2147483646]

ok> ( dup . " -> " .  f . 2drop cr ) a:each
0 -> 1
1 -> 2
10 -> 2
11 -> 4
12 -> 1
23 -> 5
-1 -> null
-2 -> null
-4 -> 1
-5 -> null
-9 -> null
2147483646 -> 31
```

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 66 bytes

```r
w=which.min
x=strtoi(intToBits(scan()));w(x[-w(x)])*any(!x[-w(x)])
```

reads from stdin; returns `0` for no second zero and the place otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v9y2PCMzOUMvNzOPq8K2uKSoJD9TIzOvJCTfKbOkWKM4OTFPQ1NT07pcoyJaF0hoxmpqJeZVaijCuf91Lf8DAA)

Answer (score 0):

## MMIX, 20 bytes (5 instrs)

xxd --jelly

```
00000000: 23ff0001 c00000ff 23ff0001 da00ff00  #”¡¢Ċ¡¡”#”¡¢ḷ¡”¡
00000010: fe010000                             “¢¡¡
```

Disassembly

```
sndz    ADDU $255,$0,1
        OR   $0,$0,$255     // x |= x + 1
        ADDU $255,$0,1
        SADD $0,$255,$0     // x = popcnt((x + 1) & ~x)
        POP  1,0
```

The algorithm is essentially the obvious "remove rightmost 0; figure out position of rightmost 0". The neat trick here is that I managed to do it without flipping all the bits first.